# Computing a non-trivial element of a proper normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

Suppose we know $G$ and $N$ are groups with $G$ non-abelian, $N\triangleleft G$ and $N\ne G$.

Further suppose that for any known $g,h\in G$ we can compute $gh$, compute $g^{-1}$ and decide if $g=1$ (that is $G$ is a black box group).

Given $a,b\in G\setminus\{1\}$ suppose we know that exactly one of these elements is in $N$ but we do not know which. Can we compute an element $g$ of $G$ that is likely to be a non-trivial element of a proper normal subgroup of $G$, that is with probability strictly greater than $1/2$?

In the case $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is non-trivial we have $[a,b]\in N$ is non-trivial as required with probability $1$, but what can we do in the case $a$ and $b$ commute?

For those who want background, this is a simplified case for the last exercise of chapter 2 in 'Permutation Group Algorithms' by Seress. I can't quite do the exercise and think this will help.

Comment: I think you need to assume $a \ne 1 \ne b$. You could try $[a,b^g]$ for random conjugates $b^g$ of $b$ in $G$. If $b$ is non-central and $[a,b^g]=1$ for a large number of $g$ then $a$ is probably in the centralizer fo the normal closure of $b$ in $G$, which is a proper normal subgroup. That would not deal with the case when $a$ and $b$ were both central in $G$, because $G$ could be cyclic with $G = \langle b \rangle$ or $\langle a \rangle$. You could resolve it by computing their orders, but that would be slow if their orders were huge.

Comment: The original exercise specifies that $G$ is non-abelian, I'll edit the question to include this. In this case if $b$ is central then the centre is a proper normal subgroup. Thanks!